# sql return blank string when there's a non-numeric value involved in function?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, aggregate

I have a simple general weighed average computation in my `SELECT`:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM((G.UnitsAcademic*GD.Grade))/SUM(G.UnitsAcademic),3) AS 'GWA'
FROM Gradesheet G 
INNER JOIN GradeSheetDetail AS GD 
    ON GD.GradesheetId=G.GradesheetId
```

However, some students have non-numeric grades (such as "No Exam") or blank grades. The code above still computes and returns a value.

I would like it to return a blank (" ") when a non-numeric value gets involved in the computation. Is there a way for SQL to do this?

Comment: what RDMS (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle...) are you using?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, MySQL 5.5

Comment: So, you've got a character field and you are doing `SUM`s on it?

Comment: okay, what is the datatypes of the selected columns? (G.UnitsAcademic and GD.Grade)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            MAX(CASE WHEN GD.Grade = 'No Grade' OR GD.Grade = ' ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN ' '
        ELSE 
            ROUND(SUM((G.UnitsAcademic*GD.Grade))/SUM(G.UnitsAcademic),3)  
    END AS 'GWA'  
FROM Gradesheet G  
INNER JOIN GradeSheetDetail AS GD  
      ON GD.GradesheetId = G.GradesheetId
```

First, you need to check if there is at least one non-numeric field, if 'yes' then return blank, else calculate aggregate.

Comment: that seems overly complicated. Why use the 1/0 switch anyway? WHEN can contain an OR directly.

Comment: I need to make decision calculate aggregate or no, only when I sure that there is no non-numeric string. And it is only possible in the way like I suggested.

Answer (score 3):

So first: Its a conceptually BAD IDEA to have numbers that shall be summed (or processed mathematically in any way) in VARCHAR fields. It would be better to store them to numeric fields (and have a different field for situations where they don't apply). (In fact I'm surprised MySQL lets you even SUM on a VARCHAR)

But I assume you can't change it so try this:

```
select CASE WHEN SUM(GD.Grade) > 0
            THEN ' ' 
            ELSE SELECT ROUND(SUM((G.UnitsAcademic*GD.Grade))/SUM(G.UnitsAcademic),3) 
            END AS 'GWA' 
            FROM Gradesheet G 
            INNER JOIN GradeSheetDetail AS GD 
                  ON GD.GradesheetId=G.GradesheetId
```

Comment: thank you. i have constraints and im not able to edit the columns. i was actually expecting it to return an error which will make my life easier hehe (i get results for records that are all numeric, error when a non numeric is involved then i just catch it). But no, the function works.

Comment: Is there something like "WHEN GD.Grade IS NOT NUMERIC" instead?

Comment: No, but you can use sum for that (I'll edit the answer in a second, had to look it up myself)

Comment: when you combine the SUM(...) here with the MAX(...) of the answer of @AndreyGuriov you get what you want. (My solution actually just works for a single line, but not for a lot of lines)